# How to check a database table and a controller and action list in C #

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making a custom authorization and for that I save in the bank database controller and action that I create in the bank, however when I delete an action or controller I can't delete it in the database automatically,
I was wondering if it is possible to compare the bank list and the list of controllers and actions and if it does not exist in the system, exclude it from the database

controller and action list

```
public static void CheckDeleteControllersAndActions(ApplicationDbContext db)
{

    var menus = db.Menus.ToList();

    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(mia.MvcApplication));

    var controlleractionlist = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
            .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
            .Select(x => new { Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name, Action = x.Name, ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name, Attributes = String.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))) })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action).ToList();

    int i = 0;

    while (i < controlleractionlist.Count)
    {
        var toCheckController = controlleractionlist[i].Controller.Replace("Controller", string.Empty);

        if (!toCheckController.Contains("Home") && !toCheckController.Contains("Sweet") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("Conta") && !toCheckController.Contains("Menus") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("Campanhas") && !toCheckController.Contains("CheckStatusMia") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("Clientes") && !toCheckController.Contains("Contratos") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("LeadLoversLogs") && !toCheckController.Contains("Listas") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("LogClientesParaExcluirs") && !toCheckController.Contains("LogFinanceiro") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("Nfe_Omie") && !toCheckController.Contains("NFEs") && !toCheckController.Contains("NFSEs") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("Pedidoes") && !toCheckController.Contains("Produtos_Servicos") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("Servicoes") && !toCheckController.Contains("Colaborador") &&
            !toCheckController.Contains("Error") && !toCheckController.Contains("OportunidadeEstagio"))
        {
            var toCheckAction = controlleractionlist[i].Action;

            if (!controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("SelectEmpresas") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("CalculaComissao") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("ConfiguraEstimativa") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("ConfiguraTaxaVariacao") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("ContratosByConsultorId") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("SelectPercentOfBusyTime") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("FiltroOportunidade") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("ContratosByConsultorId") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("_PartialTodosChamados") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("_PartialOportunidadeTimeline") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("_PartialListarFatores") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("_PartialPropostaComercial") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("ErroPage") &&
                !controlleractionlist[i].Action.Equals("SelectPercentOfBusyTime"))
            {
                foreach(var item in menus)
                {
                    var comparecontroller = string.Compare( toCheckAction, item.Action) == 0;
                }
            }
        }

        i++;

    }

}
```

some controllers are not listed and saved in the database as they are items that do not need authorization
I thank you for your help

Comment: This seems a really brittle solution.  Tying you security to your controller action names is asking for trouble.  If role based security is not a solution, you might be better off assigning each 'permit' a unique code and inside each action, check if the current user has the relevant code assigned to them.  You could even write a custom attribute to handle this if required.

Comment: hello Tintow, the system has a customized authorization, in this case it works very well, the problem is that there are items in the database that are full of useless garbage, I wanted to make the list of the controller and action as it occurs and saved in the bank in other void,
wanted a way to list the table and the controllers and actions to compare the two and if the system no longer exists, it removes it from the base

Comment: Hi Wesley, is this for a one-off exercise that you will run periodically to keep the database clean rather than something you need in your code all the time?

Comment: hello Titow, it would be only when it was necessary, but as it is more than one developer and when changes to the application body, there is always a controller or action that was unusable and remains in the bank, the last time we excluded it from the base there were more than 30 items, we want to keep the code in the application and execute it when we start the project,
because we have a screen of roles and with the controllers to select according to the roles

Comment: Ok.  And which bit is causing you the problem, getting the full list of controllers and methods or removing them from the database list?

Comment: I'm making a custom authorization and for that I save in the bank database controller and action that I create in the bank, however when I delete an action or controller I can't delete it in the database automatically, I was wondering if it is possible to compare the bank list and the list of controllers and actions and if it does not exist in the system, exclude it from the database